# How to Round to nearest 1000 in Visualforce / Formula?

Tags: visualforce, formula

How does one round a number to the nearest 1000 in Visualforce or in a formula?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Function called ROUND.

> ROUND    Returns the nearest number to a number you specify,
>   constraining the new number by a specified number of digits.
>
> `ROUND(number, num_digits)` and replace number with the field or
>   expression you want rounded; replace num_digits with the number of
>   decimal places you want to consider when rounding.

The `num_digits` is which decimal place to round `number` to.  Positive `num_digits` means to the right of the decimal point, and negative `num_digits` means to the left of the decimal point.

Since 1000 = 10^3, to round a `number` to the nearest 1000, use `ROUND(number, -3)`.

If you wanted to round a `number` to the nearest millionth, .000001 = 10^-6, use `ROUND(number, 6)`.

In other words, if you want to round a `number` to 10^n, use `ROUND(number, -n)`.